# C# Code splitting

Tags: c#, code-splitting

I am using Visual Studio in C# (.Net 4.5). I have a lot of code behind one button and it gets confusing. Can anyone tell me how I can split that code and put some of it in a separate file and link the file to the main one? I don't wish to create classes and all, operations behind that button should execute in a sequential mode. This must be simple but I can't find the solution on the web. Perhaps it is even too simple... Forgive me, I'm a total noob!

Comment: `"I dont want to create classes"` -- C# is an _object oriented_ language, why are you against creating classes?

Comment: Also, we can not even begin to help you unless you include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: Look into a design pattern such as `MVP`. Unfortunately, this would've been easier if it was done right in the beginning.

Comment: That's the reason why your code gets confusing, because is just a bunch of "Spaghetti code", almost always spending an extra hour creating some Object Oriented logic will save you in the future a lot of headaches just because the code will start telling you the business behind it. Good luck!

Comment: Your application has NameSpaces, classes, and modules.  A module is a cs extension and to put code in a different file you need a new module.  So from menu Project : Solution Explorer will open up a window.  You will see you current cs file in the solution explorer.  In the parent to the file you can right click and select Add : New : Code.  You can then add a new class object or continue an existing class by adding partial  similar to this : public partial class Form1

Comment: @maccettura, I am not "against" writing a class, but I don't think I need one for this. Also, as I wrote, the problem is that my code is getting too long. Are you suggesting that I post 700+ lines of code simply to show that it's getting long? Trust me, it's long.

Comment: @Jimenemex, according to wikipedia, MVP is a "user interface architectural pattern". I don't have a problem with my user interface, my code is simply getting too long, and I want to split it by sending some of it in another file.

Comment: @capote1789, this is not "spaghetti code". Spaghetti code is, or was, what you would get a long time ago when your code was jumping back and forth, up and down, with GOTOs and GOSUBs. It would make a sequential program listing hard to follow. My code does not jump back and forth. It's simply a long sequence of actions where each action has to be completed beore the next.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks, I will try that, and will come back later to tell you what happened. Modules...

Comment: @jdweng, in the menu, when I click "Project", I get many options, but no "Solution Explorer". But I do have a "Solution Explorer" panel on the right. Is that the same thing? When I right-click on the parent of Form1.cs, then "add", I get "new folder" and "new item" and other options but no "new code" option. Could it be "new item" instead?

Comment: @RichardL. I understand you have a lot of code but you’ll have to attempt to give us a _minimal example_ of what your code is. You shouldn’t post all of your code but you need to post **something**. This 100% needs to be refactored into a class, we need an idea of the logic you currently have so we can attempt guide you

Comment: @maccettura, I have a button, and when clicked, more than 700 lines of code execute. I want to take some of these lines and put them in another file, and call them as a function. Why does it matter what those lines of code are? Let's say its: int numbera; int numberb; int numberc; numbera=1; numberb=2; numberc=numbera+numberb; Ok? Now, what if I want to put "numbera=1; numberb=2;" in a separate file and stille have it execute when I click the button?

Comment: @RichardL. If you don’t want help that’s fine.  The question has already been closed for being too broad. If you do want help you need to ask a specific problem with enough information for us to give you an answer. The reason we need to know what your code is doing is because some things can be abstracted into classes while code pertaining to your UI will likely need to stay in the UI class.  It’s a giant red flag that you have 700 likes of code in one function. This is a very clear sign you need to refactor. You say you are a “noob” so maybe try taking our advice

Comment: The Solution Explorer is in different places in different versions of VS.  If it is alreay open great.  Then Add New Item : Code File.

Comment: @maccettura, I am looking for help, why else would I post here? I just spent my evening creating an external class and trying it out. As I thought, it doesn't do what I wanted. It doesn't have access to the variables in the main form. What I was looking for was something like the "include" or "require" we use in PHP. Just to cut some of my code and paste it in another file and use it as if it was still there in the main class. Sounds pretty simple. Most languages permit that. I'm surprised C# doesn't...

Comment: @RichardL. There is literally nothing we can do unless you tell us what you need. We have all told you to refactor your code into classes (again, C# is an object oriented language). This is 100% guaranteed to be your fix. We can’t give you anymore info beyond that since you haven’t given us anything to go by. We don’t even know what your code does or is supposed to do!  I wish you the best in figuring it all out

Comment: @maccettura, I explained many times and many ways what I  want to do. It's very simple. I have more than 700 lines of code that must execute one after the other. I want to take chunks of that code out of the main source code, put them in another file, and call them instead, like it is often done in javascript, php, or most programming language. No need to say what my code does or how i'll name the program or who will use it. Trust me, it's a lot of code, and it must execute in a sequence. That's all...

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with having class at all, and it makes thing less convoluted and clear. It's actually exactly what you want to address, as you're not happy with the code you have.

Try this, and if you're not happy with outcome, keep having long, "pythonish" function

- Split your button big logic into semantically pronounced pieces, even with comments and moving code up and down
- Create a class
- Move pieces created at 1st step into separate distinct functions
- Call them sequentially, as you want, into the "big" function of a class you've created in 2nd step
- Call that single function of newly created class from your Button click handler
- Make your class [Partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) and move different functions created on 3rd step into different files

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad practice. This anti-pattern is magic pushbutton. Changing the user interface (or adding a new interface) becomes difficult, for example, deleting a button may result in the removal of related methods.
More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps this page in the visual studio documentation is what you are looking for.

---

1. In Microsoft Visual Studio, Solution Explorer, right-click the
   project to which you want to add an existing item and click Add 
   Existing Item.
2. In the Add Existing Item -  dialog box, browse to and select the file that contains the item you want to add.
3. Click Add to create a copy of the selected file, or click the down arrow to the right of the Add button and click Add As Link to create a link to the file instead of creating a copy of the file.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-9C205780-8091-4AFE-9480-5BD69711B806-htm.html

Comment: Have you posted this in the wrong question? I am not sure how this is relevant at all